# how to publish/subscribe with remote roscore?

Tags: ros, remote-roscore, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Current setup:

1. roscore running on my remote server ( a virtual private server ) VPS
2. Machine A and B are connected to internet
3. Machine A publishes a topic "test_topic"

Result:

1. Machine A can subscribe to the topic using rostopic echo /test_topic
2. BUT Machine B  CAN NOT subscribe to the topic ( using rostopic echo /test_topic or using python/c++)
3. VPS, where roscore is running, CANNOT subscribe to the topic

However, rotopic list shows "/test_topic"!

So, is it possible to use a roscore running on a remote server and nodes connecting over internet?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32106/how-to-publish/subscribe-with-remote-roscore?/) by [Aman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2203/aman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given your firewall settings allow that and DNS settings are correct, it should be possible. See [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1